# Create stock.picking from custom module - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to create a wizard, to create a `stock.picking` from a custom module.

So far it works like this, I inherit the `stock.picking` model like this:

```
stock_picking = fields.Many2one("stock.picking", "Picking", required=True)
```

Then I inherit the fields I need:

```
state = fields.Selection(string="Estados", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.state")
launch_pack_operations = fields.Boolean(string="Iniciar operaciones con paquetes", store=True, readonly=True, related="stock_picking.launch_pack_operations")
quant_reserved_exist = fields.Boolean(string='Ya tiene quants reservados', type='boolean', help='Chequea la existencia de quants relacionados con este movimiento', related="stock_picking.quant_reserved_exist")
```

Now, my problem is, that with this way, I can CREATE a stock picking form this module, but the actual idea, is to add some products into the form of this custom module, THEN automatically create a `stock.picking` with that data.

I don't know if a button function could do the trick.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I definitly need a deeper explanation. What is the final purpose for this wizard? It will use an existing picking to create another one? What will the other picking look like?

Comment: Hi, Actually I want to create a stock.picking from this module form, but this form, doesnt have all the fields from stock.picking, so, I don't know if I'll need all the required stock.picking fields or not.

Comment: This form has: Source location (for product), Destination location (for product also), and the products themselves, the only thing this form doesn't has (and I think is a required field on a picking) is the partner, actually this is a custom module of 'fleet'.

Comment: And why do you want to use another picking for that? You could get all required fields (partner_id isn't required IIRC) within you wizard button method. For creating stock.move entries (picking entries), you have to call the product onchange method by yourself, to get all relevant fields for stock.move (uom, price, etc.).

Comment: No, it's not another picking, it's actually the picking, but the problem is that You have to create one manually from a Many2one field in this form, the idea is to create it from the custom module form, and not to go on stock from the related field and create one. Well, it could be a button, do You recommend me an example fo this function I should look for? Thanks

Comment: Slowly i understand ;-) I would do that creation/update within your custom models `create()` or `write()`. So if the list of products is changing, you could recreate or change the the move lines on the related picking. I don't know a good example for that, sorry.

Comment: Ok :) Thank You very much :) No problem